# How to use FTP to download multiple files at the same time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, vb.net-2010

I am trying to download multiple files at same time from ftp server but unable to do so,

I have tried this,

```
Const localFile As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\cr\Desktop\TE\New Folder\"
Const remoteFile As String = "/O/IE/TBML-T/FE/11/TB/"
Const host As String = "ftp://ftp4.example.com"
Const username As String = "username"
Const password As String = "password"

For i = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1

    Dim URI As String = host + remoteFile & ListBox1.SelectedItems(i)
    Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
    ftp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    ftp.KeepAlive = False
    ftp.UseBinary = True
    ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim length As Integer = response.ContentLength
            Dim bytes(length) As Byte

            'loop to read & write to file
            Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile & ListBox1.SelectedItems(i), IO.FileMode.Create)
                Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = 1
                Do
                    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                Loop Until read = 0 'see Note(1)
                responseStream.Close()
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using

        response.Close()
    End Using
Next
```

Using above code i am able to download multiple files but it downloads the second file when downloading of first file is completed and so on, Instead of that I want that the code should execute in such a way that all selected files start downloading at same time.

I think this can be done by multithreading but I am not that much familiar with that.

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO YELL

Comment: MSDN has a great [multithreaded walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that will get you there.

Comment: @Adam Zuckerman can u help me with a piece a code or a hint to do the following..

Comment: Click on the link I provided. It will give you a great deal of information.